# NOT RESIZE DialogFragment when keyboard is shown in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-dialogfragment

`dialogfragment` is resized when `keyboard` is shown.

```
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

is also not working.

how to disable `dialogfragment` resizing when `keyboard` is shown? see image

[image: here]

see manifest:

```
 <activity
            android:name=".ordering.OrderingActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"/>
```

my DialogFragment class:

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setStyle(STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.DialogFullScreen);
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Dialog dialog = getDialog();

    if(dialog != null){
        Point point = new Point();
        dialog.getWindow().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(point);

        dialog.getWindow().setLayout((int) ((point.x) * .7), ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can try full screen dialogue fragment to overcome this

Comment: You may want to try this instead: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

Comment: show the code where you are defining the properties of this DialogFragment

Comment: hi all, see new question data.  I added more codes. thanks

Comment: @pastillas did you find solution of it?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately I wasn't able to find a solution about this dialog, so instead of doing so, I transferred the dialog content to Activity for better UI/UX.

Answer (score 0):

Write following line when you creating an object of Dialog or inhering Dialog class

```
customeDialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
```

And also please put below as it is in Manifest

```
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"
```

Comment: dhaval, tried your solution. unfortunately the behavior is still same :( thanks.

Comment: Okay, Sorry I can not suggest now more than this.